# Getting an embedded Python runtime to use the current active virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I make heavy use of virtualenv to isolate my development environments from the system-wide Python installation. Typical work-flow for using a virtualenv involves running

```
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

to set the environment variables that Python requires to execute an isolated runtime. Making sure my Python executables use the current active virtualenv is as simple as setting the shebang to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Lately, though, I've been writing some C code that embeds the Python runtime. What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the embedded runtime to use the current active virtualenv. Anybody got a good example to share?

Answer (score 4):

Inspecting path and setting Py_SetProgramName worked for me:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> paths;
std::string pathEnv = getenv("PATH");
boost::split(paths, pathEnv, boost::is_any_of(";:"));
for (std::string path : paths)
{
  boost::filesystem::path pythonPath = boost::filesystem::path(path) / "python";
  std::cout << pythonPath << std::endl;
  if (boost::filesystem::exists(pythonPath))
  {
    pythonProgramName_ = pythonPath.string(); // remember path, because Py_SetProgramName doesn't save it anywhere
    Py_SetProgramName(&pythonProgramName_[0]);
    break;
  }
}
Py_Initialize();
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer to a very stale question here. You solution *looks* like it will work, but I haven't had time to verify.

Comment: I had the same question and this answer was the right one. Setting the program name to the full path of the virtualenv's python interpreter is the solution. Otherwise, the modules available in the virtualenv are not found, even if it is activated in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

> **Seems to be not an answer, but still might be useful in other contexts.**

Have you tried running `bin/activate_this.py` from your Python virtualenv? The comment in this file of my virtualenv reads:

> By using `execfile(this_file, dict(__file__=this_file))` you will
>   activate this virtualenv environment.
>
> This can be used when you must use an existing Python interpreter, not
>   the virtualenv `bin/python`

You should achieve the desired result if you execute the runtime equivalent of the above code.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with activating virtual environments. The problem is getting C/C++ code that embeds the runtime to *recognize* that it's running in a virtual environment. A solution would give a demonstration in C/C++.

Comment: This wasn't obvious to me when I read and answered the question.

Comment: An activate_this.py is only available if you created the virtualenv directory with the (non-standard) virtualenv module, but not if the directory was created with the standard venv module.

Answer (score 1):

I found that @dikobraz's answer did not work for me on mac OSX venvs because even after setting `PythonProgName`, the prefix and then `PythonHome` were still incorrectly set to system python directories.

What worked for me instead was:

```
if (auto venv_path = std::getenv("VIRTUAL_ENV")) {
    setenv("PYTHONHOME", venv_path, true);
}
```

before running `Py_Initialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [C API docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html) kind of imply it should just work (I read it as vaguely hinting the interpreter calls getenv itself), but seem to lack sufficient context to be certain, and I've never had occasion to actually test that.

Since it's apparently not working for you, what you're really looking for is probably going to be [`Py_SetPythonHome(char *home)`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#Py_SetPythonHome), which you should just need call with a copy of the string you get from `getenv("PYTHONHOME")`.

You can, of course, also modify `sys.path` for the effect of `PYTHONPATH`, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2/api/embedding.html it seems that it will just work as long as your PATH has the virtualenv directory before the pre-installed python versions. If not, try setting PYTHONHOME as mentioned by Nicholas Knight.

Answer (score 0):

You can the check the environment variable VIRTUAL_ENV to get the current envs location.